# iTunes m4a -> MP3 CD?

Tags: music, mp3, file-converter, itunes

One of the most frustrating feature omissions in iTunes, IMO, is the fact that there is no easy way to burn an MP3 CD if your songs aren't already MP3s.

Is there any software out there that can take an iTunes playlist, duplicate all the files, convert the M4A files to MP3, then burn an MP3 CD?

Comment: What OS? Gratis or commercial?

Comment: try Media Human audio converter if you are on a PC

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg fully supports m4a file types (and pretty much everything else too). A quick linux/mac script to do this would be:

```
find /path/to/directory/with/files -name '*.m4a' -exec ffmpeg -i {} {}.mp3 \;
```

run from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

[**Format Factory**](http://format-factory.en.softonic.com/) converts bulk of M4A files into MP3 keeping the original files unaltered.
It also converts many other audio formats like MP3, WMA, APE, FLAC, AAC, MMF, AMR, M4A, M4R, OGG, WAV and WavPack

You can use IMGBURN to make a CD of those mp3 files.